# Binding correcture (BCOR) on wrong side when using single A3 page in A4 document

Tags: margins, koma-script

I have one single A3 page in my scrbook to show a big figure in landscape format. My document is twosided with BCOR=17mm. On the single A3 page is a new chapter. So it starts on a uneven page and then the bigger margin should be on the left side. But it is on the wrong side, on the right side... I have no problems with the margins on my A4 sides...

Here my code as a minimal example:

```
\documentclass
[   twoside,        
    12pt,            
    DIV=15,          
    BCOR=17mm,       
    headsepline,    
    openright,       
    a4paper,         
    listof=totoc,      
    bibliography=totoc,        
]   {scrbook}

\begin{document}
 Here I am writing on my A4 page.

\cleardoublepage
\KOMAoptions{DIV=15, BCOR=17mm,paper=A3,paper=landscape, pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\chapter{Anhang}\label{ch:Anhang}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{Bilder/Sequence_Diagram}
    \caption{Figure caption}
    \label{fig:Sequence_Diagram}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

So I want to change the wrong margin side on this specific single A3 page, can anyone help me please? I googled a lot but it doesnt work...

Answer (score 1):

I could not compile your example for reproducing:

- The package grapicx is not loaded.
- I don't have "Bilder/Sequence_Diagram".

So I modified.

When compiling the following example, the A3 page has number 3 which is an odd number and therefore is a recto-page.
With left-to-right-language-books recto-pages are righthand-pages. Thus your A3-page is a righthand-page.
The bigger margin with righthand-pages usually is on the right.  This is the case with your A3-page.
When changing the A3-page's BCOR, this affects the A3-page's left margin which seems correct to me because with righthand-pages the binding is at the left.

So I don't see something going wrong.

A righthand-page should have the smaller left margin plus the binding correction on the left side.
This does not exclude the case of left margin plus binding correction being smaller than the right margin.
E.g., -as far as I know-  with scrbook with A3-landscape-paper without binding-correction with righthand-pages the left margin is 2.8cm and the right margin is 5.6cm. If you add 1.7cm binding-correction to the left margin, this is a total of 2.8cm + 1.7cm = 4.5cm which is still smaller than the right margin.
So even with binding-correction it is correct that the bigger margin is on the right.

```latex
\documentclass
[   twoside,        
    12pt,            
    DIV=15,          
    BCOR=17mm,       
    headsepline,    
    openright,       
    a4paper,         
    listof=totoc,      
    bibliography=totoc,        
]   {scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 Here I am writing on my A4 page.

\cleardoublepage
\KOMAoptions{DIV=15, BCOR=17mm,paper=A3,paper=landscape, pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\chapter{Anhang}\label{ch:Anhang}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth, height=.75\textheight]{example-grid-100x100pt}%
    \caption{Figure caption}%
    \label{fig:Sequence_Diagram}%
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

Terminal-output to show version/release numbers of programs/packages used for compiling—typearea complains about things not being beautiful and "thinks" that the lines are too wide for text looking good and is not aware that the lines don't contain text but an image:

```
 pdflatex-dev test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex-dev)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-05-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2021-2-27 branch)
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize12pt.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2]

Package typearea Warning: Bad type area settings!
(typearea)                The detected line width is about 122%
(typearea)                larger than the heuristically estimated maximum
(typearea)                limit of typographical good line width.
(typearea)                You should e.g. decrease DIV, (increase fontsize)
(typearea)                or change papersize.

chapter 1.

Overfull \hbox (0.56653pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 23--24
 [][] 
[3 </usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-grid-100x100pt.pdf
>] (./test.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2020/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmssbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmss8.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (3 pages, 37699 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: Thank you Ulrich for your response. But when printing my whole latex document and binding it, the A3 page has the bigger margin on the wrong side. Do you know maybe how to change that even though it might be not the 100% correct workflow?

Yes my A3 page is a recto page, but recto pages should have the bigger margin on the left side because there is the binding isn't ist? But the bigger margin on my case is on the right

Comment: @Lena The righthand-page should have the smaller left margin plus the binding correction on the left side. This does not exclude the case of left margin plus binding correction being smaller than the right margin. E.g., - afaik-  with scrbook with A3-landscape-paper without binding-correction with righthand-pages the left margin is 2.8cm and the right margin is 5.6cm. If you add 1.7cm binding-correction to the left margin, this is a total of 2.8cm + 1.7cm = 4.5cm which is still smaller than the right margin. So even with binding-correction it is correct that the bigger margin is on the right.

Comment: Okay thank you again for your explanation. How can I change the margins in my example only for the A3 Page? I dont want to have a big margin on the right side.

Comment: @Lena As your example contains the word "Anhang" I suppose you speak German. The official German-language-documentation for Koma-Script classes like scrbook is [scrguide.pdf](https://komascript.de/~mkohm/scrguide.pdf). Teil I, Kapitel 2 "Satzspiegelberechnung mit typearea.sty" might be of interest to you. One possibility could be increasing the DIV-value with the A3-page.

Comment: Thank you Ulrich, increasing the DIV was the solution! DANKE! :D